Mix jaxb and xml transformer with MarshallingWebServiceInboundGateway?
I have soap web service with 2 operations. Each operation use a Request and Response wrapper elements with xml data inside. The data in Response2 is the more complex.
With Spring Integration WS, I have a channel who expose these 2 operations and do routing to endpoints back office. The channel is created with MarshallingWebServiceInboundGateway and it works fine.
But I have a contraint : the Response2 data have to be transmitted to back office even if the data doesn't respect the xsd schema. Indeed, the external systems who consume the soap web service can send some invalid data and I can do nothing about that.
But the back office is able to treat xml invalid data. And the problem is here : the choice based on a Jaxb2Marshaller implementation doesn't work well with some xml invalid data. The marshalling/unmarshalling operations can fail with invalid data (and I know it's the expected behaviour). For example, a empty xml value can't be marshal in a Double java type.
Seen that it works fine with valid data, I search a solution to replace the jaxb marshalling mechanism for the Response2 only. This mechanism  will need to extract the xml data as-is under Response2 wrapper element and put it in a String variable. But keep the jaxb mechanism for the others because it works well.
Is there a way to do that ? to mix jaxb with other xml transformer in Spring Integration WS ?
Versions : Spring boot 3.2.4, Spring Integration WS 6.2.3, Java 21, Spring integration DSL
I tried but without success :

replace "@XmlElement BusinessData data;" by "String data" in the Response2 wrapper class. but it doens't woork because it's xml format inside and there is not cdata tag.
replace "@XmlElement BusinessData data;" by "@XmlElementHandler" but it doesn't work too
do some researchs about SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway

